# High memory usage on fresh boot

Tags: linux-mint

[image: htop output]

I'm using nvidia driver but for some reason Xorg service keeps running (I don't know if it's related to nvidia driver or not) and using lots of ram. Other processes seems to be using adequate amount of ram. Is it normal for xorg to be running despite of nvidia drivers chosen from driver manager? How can I check for "startup-enabled" non root services and disable them one by one?

Comment: Do not post images where plain text will do.

Comment: If you do not want Xorg running, try `sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target` and reboot. You will then have the Nvidia cards available for rendering or compute but the desktop will not be taking up CPU or memory resources.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing high memory usage on a fresh boot, especially with Xorg consuming a significant amount of RAM. It's possible that some background processes or services are contributing to this issue. Here are steps along with commands, you can take to troubleshoot and optimize your system:

Check NVIDIA Driver Configuration:

Command: `nvidia-smi`

Additionally, you can check the Xorg logs for any error messages related to the NVIDIA driver using this command:

`cat /var/log/Xorg.0.log | grep -i nvidia`

Check Running Processes:

Command: `htop`

Check Xorg Processes:

Command: `ps aux | grep Xorg`

Check Enabled Services:

Command: `systemctl list-unit-files --state=enabled`

Look for services related to graphics, display managers, or Xorg. If you find any suspicious services, you can disable them using this command:

`sudo systemctl disable <service-name>`

> Note: You need to replace the 'service-name' with the actual service name in the above command which you want to disable/stop.

I hope this information helps solve your issue, remember to approach the troubleshooting process cautiously and avoid disabling essential services. If you are unsure about a particular service, it's a good idea to research it before making any changes. Additionally, always back up important data before making significant system modifications.